# Retrieving database data in android

Tags: android, database

i was using SQLiteHelper to store data in a database, data was correctly stored (opened with SQLite viewer), but when i have to get data from DB, my code returns null values always

```
public class HistorySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE History (artist TEXT, title TEXT, link TEXT)";

    public HistorySQLiteHelper(Context context, String nombre, CursorFactory factory, int version){
            super(context, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnterior, int versioNueva){
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS History");
            db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }
}
```

And this is the code i use to retrieve data

```
 String[] fields = new String[] {"artist", "title", "link"};


                    HistorySQLiteHelper hdbh = new HistorySQLiteHelper(HistoryActivity.this, "DBHistory", null, 1);
                    SQLiteDatabase db = hdbh.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor c = db.query("History", fields, "artist=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(0)}, null, null, null);

                    int counter = 0;

                    artist = new String[30];
                    title = new String[30];
                    links = new String[30];

                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                    artist[counter] = c.getString(0);
                                    title[counter] = c.getString(1);
                                links[counter] = c.getString(2);
                                    counter++;
                            } while (c.moveToNext());
                    }
                    db.close();

       if (artist.length < 1){
            String[] strings = nee Stting[]{" No results. "};
                            adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HistoryActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
                            list.setAdapter(adaptador);
               }else{
                            AdaptadorTitulares adapter = new AdaptadorTitulares(HistoryActivity.this);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                    list.setClickable(true);
            }
    }
```

And ArrayAdapter class:

```
    class AdaptadorTitulares extends ArrayAdapter {

        Activity context;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                AdaptadorTitulares(Activity context) {
                super(context, R.layout.listitem_titular, artist);
                this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
                        View item = convertView;
                        ViewHolder holder;

                if(item == null)
                {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_titular, null);

                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.titulo = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblTitulo);

                        item.setTag(holder);
                }
                else
                {
                        holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
                }

                        holder.titulo.setText(artist[position]);

                        return(item);
                }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titulo;
    }
```

Why does my code give null values and how to solve it?

PD: here are variable fields and onCreate method

```
public class HistoryActivity extends Activity{

private ListView list;
private String[] artist;
private String[] title;
private String[] links;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.history_list); 

    new LoadTask().execute(); //this is where I put the code to retrieve data

} ////////////////////////////////       onCreate END
```

Comment: Add Actual code here which you have used.

Comment: is there any artists with value equals 0? you are querying artists with value 0?

Comment: Updated post. @aprian no, artists are all strings with no numbers

Comment: @BamsBamx that's why it is returning no rows then. see your 2nd part of code, at `Cursor c = db.query(...,new String[] {String.valueOf(0)},...);`, change the 0 to one of the artists value to see if it return something.

Comment: Okay did it... But i only gives me values which appear in the table... For example, in the table appears hatebreed 1 time, so if i change the 0 with "hatebreed" it gives me one value with string "hatebreed".... I think tha when I put 0 it gives me all null values because it didnt appear in the list

Comment: But I still need to retrive all artist.... What should I do?

Comment: I tried to replace String.valueOf(0), with null, got nothing again :(

Comment: `Cursor c = db.query("History", fields, null, null, null, null, null);` this query will return all the records.

Comment: Yes, i realized of that could work...it worked.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I know which was my error. I declared `Cursor` like this:

```
Cursor c = db.query("History", fields, "artist=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(0)}, null, null, null);
```

With this, I only obtained those values with `artists = "0"`.

What I wanted to do was retrieve all values from all columns.. For that i had to declare 3rd and 4th params as `null`

```
Cursor c = db.query("History", fields, null, null, null, null, null);
```